# Como calcular valor de duas subquery no Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, oracle18c

Como se calcula duas subquery no Oracle?

Poderiam me explicar como faço a soma do `VALOR_1` + `VALOR_2`?

```
SELECT COL1
, (SELECT SUM(TAB1.VLRTOTAL)
    FROM TABELA TAB1
    WHERE TAB1.ID = TAB3.ID) AS VALOR_1

, (SELECT SUM(TAB2.VLRTOTAL)
    FROM TABELA2 TAB2
    WHERE TAB2.ID = TAB4.ID) AS VALOR_2

FROM TABELA3 TAB3, TABELA4 TAB4
WHERE TAB4.ID = TAB2.ID
AND TAB2.ID <= 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta realizar um subselect dessas informações:

```
select dados1+dados2
  from (Select (select seuselectdados1) as dados1
             , (select seuselectdados2) as dados2
          from table
      ) as tab_temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado a colaboração de todos, mais resolvi desse modo:

Muito obrigado.

```
, (SELECT NVL(SUM(TAB1.VLRTOTAL),0)
    FROM TABELA TAB1
    WHERE TAB1.ID = TAB3.ID) AS VALOR_1

, (SELECT NVL(SUM(TAB2.VLRTOTAL),0)
    FROM TABELA2 TAB2
    WHERE TAB2.ID = TAB4.ID) AS VALOR_2

, (SELECT NVL(SUM(TAB1.VLRTOTAL),0)
    FROM TABELA TAB1
    WHERE TAB1.ID = TAB3.ID)+
, (SELECT NVL(SUM(TAB2.VLRTOTAL),0)
    FROM TABELA2 TAB2
    WHERE TAB2.ID = TAB4.ID) AS AS SOMATOTAL


FROM TABELA3 TAB3, TABELA4 TAB4
WHERE TAB4.ID = TAB2.ID
AND TAB2.ID <= 10
```